# @aws-sdk/client-s3 new SDK version v3 - Region is missing error

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am migrating S3 client on node.js from v2 to v3. And getting error: `Region is missing`, when using any command: `s3Client.send(\\any command\\);`
I have the latest libraries v3.405.0 and initialise S3 with this code:

```js
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

async function getData() {
  const s3Client = new S3Client([
    {
      region: "eu-central-1",
      accessKeyId: "xx",
      secretAccessKey: "xx"
    }
  ]);

  const command = new ListObjectsV2Command({
    Bucket: "dev-env",
    Delimiter: "/",
    Prefix: "orders/2022-02/2021000382-284/28/"
  });
  const data = await s3Client.send(command);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

getData();
```

I have tried also in sandbox only the library and getting same error.
Any idea?

Comment: I have updated creating the client like this:
```const s3Client = new S3Client( [ { region: 'eu-central-1', credentials: { accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET } } ] );
```
And it is throws same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra array in input of your S3 client instantiation.

Here's the correct syntax:

```js
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region:'eu-central-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: ACCESS_KEY_SECRET
    }
});
```

I've integrated this correction in your code, tested with the same library version and it works:

```js
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

async function getData() {
  const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region:'eu-central-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "xxx",
        secretAccessKey: "xxx"
    }
  });

  const command = new ListObjectsV2Command({
    Bucket: "dev-env",
    Delimiter: "/",
    Prefix: "orders/2022-02/2021000382-284/28/"
  });
  const data = await s3Client.send(command);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

getData();
```

Comment: yep, I had this wrong. But the error remains same :-/

Comment: I tried your exact code, only changing the bucket name and other options in the List command, and it worked perfectly. I have updated my answer with the full code; please try copying and pasting it to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. I placed S3Client configuration into array (because WS show me with intellisence, that it is an array). But it is not :).